# Query to Get Maximum 2 Replies from Each Topic

Tags: mysql

I would like the table to return maximum 2 replies from each topic using right join. May I know how can I do that?

```
Topic table
+--------+
|  tid   |
+--------+
|  1     | 
|  2     |
|  3     |
|  4     |
+--------+


Reply table
+--------+--------+
|  rid   |  tid   |
+--------+--------+
|  1     |    1   |
|  2     |    1   |
|  3     |    1   |
|  4     |    2   |
|  5     |    2   |
|  6     |    2   |
|  7     |    4   |
|  8     |    4   |
|  9     |    4   |
+--------+--------+

Result
+--------+--------+
|  tid   |  rid   |
+--------+--------+
|  1     |    1   |
|  1     |    2   |
|  2     |    4   |
|  2     |    5   |
|  3     |  null  |
|  4     |    7   |
|  4     |    8   |
+--------+--------+
```

Comment: If a topic has more than 2 replies, what criteria, if any, is used to select the chosen 2?

Comment: @JRD, no criteria, based on time or can be just random any two

Comment: This article may be helpful: http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/

Answer (score 0):

How about this Top-N query:

```
select tid, rid from(
    select t.tid, r.rid,
           case when @tid is not null and @tid != t.tid then @rn := 0 else null end reset_rn,
           @tid := t.tid tid_change,
           @rn := @rn + 1 rn
    from   topic t
    left join reply r on t.tid = r.tid
    join (select @rn := 0, @tid := null) rn
    order by t.tid, r.rid
) q
where rn < 3;
```

The key to what 2 rows are kept is the `order by` in the inner query.